# Strange DataWindow sort with negative numeric string

Tags: sorting, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a sortable DataWindow in PowerBuilder (both 9 and 12.6) that is giving me the collywobbles. I have a field called Category, defined as a Char(4). The form that populates this field restricts it to 4 numeric characters. Smartass tester me saw that and went "Hmm, that doesn't disallow negatives, does it?" and checked. It didn't. Then I tried sorting by that field. If I do the query in Oracle, it sorts as predicted, with the -001 at the top. If I take the DataWindow, though, which starts out sorted by Obj_No, and tell it to sort by Category instead, it sorts in the following order:

```
...
0009
-001
0010
...
```

I'm having the darnedest time coming up with a reason that would ever make sense. Anyone else?

ETA: @avk, it looks kind of like this.

```
IF ls_sort_cols[i] <> '-' THEN ls_sort_str = ls_sort_str+' '+ls_sort_cols[i]+' A'
IF len(ls_sort_str) > 0 THEN
    ldw_win.setsort(ls_sort_str)
    ldw_win.sort()
END IF
```

I've confirmed that the value of ls_sort_str going into the SetSort line is "category A".

Comment: Strange indeed. Can you show me the setSort() line you are using getting you this result?

Comment: If you want the sort to work properly you should convert the string to a number first (e.g. Sort by: Integer(Character) ) because character sorts will sort numbers funky if they are different length numbers. Did you check the return code of the SetSort and Sort statements?

Comment: @DisplacedGuy, I didn't, but I wouldn't expect a problematic return code, as all the other categories sorted as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to code it like this:

```
IF len(ls_sort_cols) > 0 THEN
    ldw_win.reset()
    ldw_win.ImportString( ls_sort_cols)
    ldw_win.setsort("category A")
    ldw_win.sort()
END IF
```